# Download html file from URL on Xarmain for android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin studio and developing for an android platform (c#).
I am looking for away to download the html of the specific URL, I prefer a method using webview client.

I found this link : http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_a_file/ that is grate but it is for the IOS and not for the android and I can't fiend anything like this for the android.

I really searched for the whole web to fiend some thing like this and with no luck so if anyone have a guide or example of how to do this I would be very thankful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [WebClient is part of .Net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and is not iOS specific you can use exactly same code on Android as in [link you gave](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_a_file/)... Only difference is last part "InvokeOnMainThread" which is on Android "RunOnUiThread". See bottom of [this page](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/) for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and i think there is few more differences because xamarin don't recognize my code. I don't know why yet but I will keep tiring so thank you.

Comment: On default generated Android project I changed just button.Click content: https://gist.github.com/DavidKarlas/8723938894ccefae6131
And this works... What I also had to do is add "using System.Net;" at top of file.